# How to set default value in drop-down list in JSP?

Tags: jsp, frontend

Currently, I have the following JSP code to display Yes or No using a `c:choose` block:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${doc.flag eq 'Y'}">Yes</c:when>
    <c:when test="${doc.flag eq 'N'}">No</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

I want to make this editable by changing it into a drop-down list but with the default value selected between Yes or No as per `doc.flag` being Y or N respectively. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below :

```
<select name="somename">
 <option ${doc.flag eq 'Y' ? 'selected' : ''}>Yes</option>
 <option ${doc.flag eq 'N' ? 'selected' : ''}>No</option>
</select>
```